# Typescript import syntax problems

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, compatibility, es6-modules, ecmascript-2016

I'm new to Typescript and I've problems when I use **import/export** syntax in the browser.
The terminal/compiler doesn't throw any kind of error. But google's console says:

> **GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/modules/file1.mod net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

Simply, **I want to import a module** inside my main file(main.ts)

**index.html**

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"module": "ES2015",                          
"rootDir": "./src/",   
"target": "ES2016",                                 
"lib": ["DOM", "ES2019"],  
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

this is **main.ts** and it has to import a simple constant(pigreco)

```
import { pigreco } from './modules/file1.mod'; 
console.log(pigreco);
```

Comment: Well do you have a */modules/file1.mod* module (and does your setup serve it to the browser)?

Comment: yes, I want to serve it to the browser.

Comment: Well the error message says that you aren't doing it. What web server are you using? Where is that *file1.mod* located? What are its contents?

Comment: @Bergi The main problem is: Typescript alone can transpile a code that can be read by the browser? ES6 or CommonJS can be understood by Google etc.? Am I forced to use Webpack/Rollup etc.?

Comment: ES6 modules are supported by browsers, yes. CommonJS, no.

Comment: in the tsconfig, i see many programmers set the option of "module" to "CommonJS". But in this way the code will be transpiled with CommonsJs and that's a problem i think right? Situation is different with node naturally.

Comment: Or they use another tool that will further bundle the commonjs modules to something usable in the browser, or they don't use `tsc` for transpilation at all (but only for typechecking), or yes they might use node…

Answer (score 1):

just add **.ts** to the end of your import.
`import { pigreco } from './modules/file1.mod.ts';`
it should work.